# Difference between a VM Consume and VM Listener in Mule 4?

Tags: mule-component, mulesoft, mule4

1. I'm trying to find out subtle differences between a VM Consume and VM Listener connectors. But couldn't able to find my links. Any help here is of much help.
2. I have a VM publish in one of my flow, and had a VM listener in another flow. At this point VM Listener was able to catch the queue published by VM publish. But when i changed the VM listener to VM Consume I couldn't able to consume the queue which was published by VM publish. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

- **VM Consume**-This component acts as a **event** **processor** only to poll a queue.Since this acts as a event processor it has to be called either from a **event** **source** or through flow-ref and cannot act as a event source.
- **VM Listener**-This acts as the **event source** only and gets triggered whenever a message is post to the queue on which this VM Listener is polling.This component cannot act as a event processor.

2.Please refer to the explanation in 1, and you will understand. You can post your flows here and I'll be happy to help with whatever issue you are facing.